# Unit testing issue with bundling in a SPA

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a single page app with bundling. It is taking too much time to unit test when i make a change in the js file as i have to go through the following steps

1. Gulp (Happens when project is compiled in Visual studio)
2. Open chrome and start right from the login page
3. Navigate to the page by clicking next-> next->next.

Is there any trick available to avoid going through these steps everytime??

Comment: *E2E/integration testing!* Basically, unit tests, but with browser automation.

Answer (score 1):

For your unit tests, if you are using karma, you must've installed karma-chrome-launcher. use karma-phantomjs-launcher. install it using:-

```
npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
```

and also update karma.conf.js

```
karma start karma.conf.js --single-run
```

(alternatively, u can set single-run: true, in the config as well)

now u don't have to interact with chrome/browser interface.